# Static classes...is it OK to do this?

Tags: c#, class, static

I read When to Use Static Classes in C# but the top answer didn't necessarily answer my question. I've an application that interfaces with quite a bit of similar hardware, via an HTTP server. Each device must be logged into and the credentials are normally the same. I'm using Properties.Settings.Default.etc to handle application wide settings; however, for the ease I keep track of the last used username/password when individually logging into a device. The defaults that are settable through an options window are used first and remain the same unless changed via the options window, despite the temporary settings changing and being used in the defaults stead.

Anyway, that's the scenario...with regards to the question, I'm doing this:

```
private static class TemporarySettings
{
    public static string Username = Properties.Settings.Default["Username"].ToString();
    public static string Password = Properties.Settings.Default["Password"].ToString();
}
```

Is that stupid?

Comment: Umm...I had a quote in the title...

Static classes...is it "OK" to use them for internal property management - or something like that

Comment: Ok, what if taken even further and I did...

private static class EventHandlers
{
    /* ... */
}

And contained all of my event handlers in the class? I'm more or less going for readability and useful/convenient organization...

Comment: @Berdon Magnus, please don't use a static event handler class, you'll create a side-effect that resembles a memory leak. This is because the event publisher holds references to its subscribers.  See Jon Skeet's answer to another question: http://is.gd/JkT1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not stupid, and it may solve your problem perfectly (if it does, don't change it).  There are some problems that this approach might cause down the road, though, and it helps to know what those are.

1. If you want to change the user name and password without restarting your application, you won't have that option. You can write logic to watch the config file for change and reload the values if they change.
2. If you want to "reuse" your code (especially if you put more behavior like monitoring for change) for multiple sets of username and password, you'll need to convert this to an instance.
3. If you ever want to unit test classes that depend on this class, you will have a very difficult time stubbing the values.

To reiterate, though, you shouldn't shy away from the simplest solution (as you have defined) because of these *potential* issues unless you think there's a realistic chance that you'll be burned by them in the future.  Otherwise, it will probably not be a very difficult refactoring to switch to an instance class later when the need arises.

Answer (score 1):

Even better, mark them `readonly` or use properties that only have a getters.

Comment: The reason I don't mark them as readonly is because I do actually change them depending on whether the user enters in a different username/password to keep semi-persistent data aside from the actual persistent settings.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting username and password to the same value, but other than that, no.

Comment: Heh - my copying and pasting and removal of a few things led to that... :P